# How do I check if a date is between 2 dates?

Tags: ios, numbers, iwork

[image: Example tables]

In the above example, how would I get the “period” (column C of the Example table) of a certain date (column B of the Example 2 table) using the start and end dates (columns A and B of the Example table)? Basically I want to detect if a date is in between certain dates and return a value to the right of it (kind of like VLOOKUP).

Comment: did  you try something like this example `=LOOKUP(2,1/((B5>=mins)*(B5<=maxs)),results)`